# How delete or replace dot - python read file excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have excel data as follows and I want to convert the dot to a comma,but I tried many ways but couldn't.

Here is a sample data:

[image: Sample 1]

[image: Sample 2]

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel('zxc.xlsx',header=0)

data['V'] = (data['V'].replace('\.','', regex=True)

print(data)
```

Comment: you will save the data in another file?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Enjoy the [tour], read [ask] and please inline images using __exclamation-mark__ before link: `![image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxBpw.png)`

Comment: I don't think how this could work. Because numpy array implicitly convert your input value into float64 array. So once loaded into data frame, values are float.

Comment: So is there any other way for me to convert the dot to a comma?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the type data of your df to string , you can use that.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('excel.xlsx',header=0)
data = data.astype(str)
data['d'] = [x.replace('.', ',') for x in data['d']]
data['c'] = [x.replace('.', ',') for x in data['c']]
data['v'] = [x.replace('.', ',') for x in data['v']]
print(data)
```